# Mac Scipy Installation Error like dlopen, no architecture found etc

Tags: python-2.7, numpy, scipy, pandas

While running some scipy , numpy and pandas job, I was stumbled in the very first step that it to import and got many error like

> dlopen , no architecture found  , yada yada....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is quite simple. Just follow the below steps which requires removal of Scipy if its already installed or fresh installation.

if Scipy is already installed then follow the following steps.

1. Go to the site-package directory i.e.

   cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
2. Remove the scipy which in my case was .egg file

   sudo rm -rf scipy-0.12.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg

Freshly install the Scipy with .dmg and not port, easy_install, fink or anything else.

> http://sourceforge.net/projects/scipy/files/scipy/0.10.0b2/